# java compare array elements

Tags: java, arrays

i have a problem with an exam test.
I have two arrays: int[] a, int[] b, with random values.
E1 return true if there are two elements of b greater then each element of a.
How do I write "there are two elements of b greater than each element of a"?
I can write "there is ONE elements of b greater than each element of a" in this way:

```
public static boolean e1(int[] a, int[] b){
    boolean ris = false;
    boolean ogniA = true;
    int i = 0;
    if(a != null && a.length != 0){ 
        while(ogniA && i<a.length){
            boolean es1= false;
            boolean es2 = false;
            int j = 0;

            if(b!= null && b.length != 0){  
                while(!es1 && j < b.length){
                    if(j%2!=0){
                        es1 = a[i] < b[j];
                    } 

                    j++;

                }ris = es1 ;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return ris;
```

I need something like this. Thanks for help.

Comment: Find two biggest elements in `b` and check if each is bigger then max from `a`.

Comment: Do you want to solve the problem without using java api ?

Answer (score 0):

So I would solve this problem, by dividing it into smaller problems.
1st you need to find the 2 biggest values in the first array.
I presume this should be abstract and work for every array

Code (using the example from Andronicus):

"E1 return true if there are two elements of b greater then each element of a"

Basically you need the second greater value of array B and the greater value of the array A

```
int[] a = {3, 5, 7, 9};
int[] b = {2, 4, 3, 10, 11};

int secondGreatestOfB = IntStream.of(b).boxed()
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .limit(2)
            .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .limit(1)
            .findFirst().orElse(0);

System.out.println(areTheTwoBiggestNumbersOfArrayBbiggerThanAllValuesFromArrayA(a, secondGreatestOfB));

private static boolean areTheTwoBiggestNumbersOfArrayBbiggerThanAllValuesFromArrayA(int[] a, int secondGreatestOfArrayB) {
    return secondGreatestOfArrayB > IntStream.of(a).max().orElse(0);
}
```